# stl error for remove and find_if

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm using `vector<clsStudent*>` student for polymorphism, as I have derived local student and international student from base class student. the problem now is I have errors for my functor. I have two methods for deleting. Both are not working. How do I fix this? and which delete method is better?

```
void deleteStudent(vector <clsStudent*>& student)
{
    cout << "Enter student name to delete";
    student.erase(remove(student.begin(), student.end(), nameToDelete), student.end());

    vector <clsStudent*>::iterator it = student.begin();
    while (it != student.end())
    {
         if (*it == nameToDelete)
         {
             it = student.erase(it);
         }
         else{
             ++it;
         }
     }
}

void searchStudent(const vector <clsStudent*>& s)
{
    string searchName;

    cout << "\nEnter student name to search for. Press [Q] to terminate." << endl;
    cin >> searchName;


    if (s.size() == 0)
        cout << "There is 0 student in the database.";

    while(searchName != "q")
    {
        vector<clsStudent*>::iterator it = std::find_if(s.begin(),
                                                s.end(),
                                                MatchName(searchName)); <---- ERROR here
}

int main()
{
    char choice;
    clsUniversityProgram objProgram[3];
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        objProgram[x].programInfo();
    }
    vector <clsStudent*> student;

    do
    {
    cout <<"\nPress [A] to add new student"
        << "\nPress [L] to list existing stundet"
        << "\nPress [M] to modify existing student"
        << "\nPress [O] to sort student data by name"
        << "\nPress [W] to write students data to file"
        << "\nPress [R] to read students data from file"
        << "\nPress [D] to delete a student"
        << "\nPress [X] to exit"
        << "\nEnter your choice: " << endl;
        choice = toupper(getch());

        switch(choice){
        case 'A':
            addStudents(student, objProgram);
            break;
        case 'L':
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < student.size(); x++)
            {
                student[x]->printStudentDetails();
                student[x]->print();
            }
            break;
        }
        case 'M':
            // modify
        case 'O':
            sortStudentbyName(student);
            break;
        case 'W':
            // write
            break;
        case 'R':
            // read
            break;
        case 'D':
            deleteStudent(student);
            break;
        case 'X':
            return 0;
        default:
            cerr << "Invalid input!" << endl;
            break;
        }
   } while (choice != 'L'
            && choice != 'M'
            && choice != 'O'
            && choice != 'W'
            && choice != 'R'
            && choice != 'D');
    return 0;
}
struct MatchName
    {
      MatchName(string& searchName) : s_(searchName) {}
      bool operator()(const clsStudent* student) const
      {
        return student->getName() == s_;
      }
     private:
      string s_;
    };
```

Errors

`error: conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<clsStudent* const*, std::vector<clsStudent*> >' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<clsStudent*>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<clsStudent**, std::vector<clsStudent*> >}' requested|`

Comment: You should really post `MatchName`.

Comment: why include the io code in `main` but not `MatchName`'s signature  which is used on the line that the error occurs?  Why not include a copy of the actual error?

Comment: I edited your question to use \` characters around code so that `<>` characters are not treated as HTML, please use the preview before posting your question to ensure it is formatted correctly (and please take an extra few seconds to write correct English, e.g. _I'm_ not _im_).

Comment: Sorry forgot about the matchName.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks. Will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `find_if` is that `s` is a const reference to the vector, but the iterator you're returning is non-const, so try changing to:

```
vector<clsStudent*>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(...)
```

Or if you're using a C++11 compiler, then you can you use `auto` to infer the correct const/non-const iterator for you:

```
auto it=std::find_if(...)
```

You haven't posted the error for the call to `remove`, but I suspect it's because you really intended to write:

```
remove_if(student.begin(), student.end(), MatchName(nameToDelete))
```

Answer (score 1):

the error you report comes from your searchStudent method.

your vector is const, so you can't use iterator, use const_iterator instead